# ActionBar tab styles in horizontal view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-styles

When using a phone or a tablet in portrait mode, tabs are shown under the ActionBar that constains the logo and menu items. On tablets in horizontal mode they are shown inline with the logo and menu items. In this configuration the underscore under the seleced tab is lost.

What style controls this? In portrait mode I want to use a different selected style than in landscape mode when tabs are shown inline with the logo and menu.

My theme has it's parent set to `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. Under it I have

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Silence</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Silence</item>
```

`android:actionBarTabStyle` has `android:background` value set to a drawable that is

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_silence" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_silence" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_silence" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_silence" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_silence" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_silence" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_silence" />
</selector>
```

I see these `state_selected` values. The image that is set as the drawable for these is different color than the ActionBar background, so it's not just that I can't see them on top of the same colored background.

Style for `actionBarStyle` contains

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_silence</item>
<item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_silence</item>
<item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_silence</item>
<item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Silence</item>
```

The three first ones are images and the `progressBarStyle` contains some styles too, but they are irrelevant.

Comment: Did you check this for various API levels(or on what version are you seeing that behavior?)?

Comment: @Luksprog I only have devices running Android 4.1.2 and 4.3. How could I use completely different image for inline tabs?

Comment: `actionBarTabStyle` is responsible for that selector. I've never saw a problem with disappearing tab indicators when the tabs are inline. *How could I use completely different image for inline tabs?* - the system chooses how to place those tabs, a landscape orientation will probably put them as inline. So, you could use configuration identifiers for `-land` and change the theme to the desired selector. I would recommend against this, I'm not sure I've ever seen an app that does this, it would be very counter intuitive for the user.

Answer (score -1):

You should be interested in ActionBarTabStyle.

To use different images for inline tabs you can assume that it represents landscape mode and create a custom selector for landscape mode.

If you want complete set of options to try out, check this out
http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator
Download the zip, replace the generated images with your own png files and add the style in your project.